# How to add remove class on button if atleast one checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to add/remove a class on button if at least one checkbox is checked, from list of checkboxes, 
HTML is like this

```
<button class="add-tag disabled"></button>
<button class="remove-tag disabled"></button>

<table id="product_table">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
</table>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).on('change','#product_table input:checkbox' , function(){

        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $('.add-tag').removeClass("disabled");
                $('.remove-tag').removeClass("disabled");
                console.log('got checked');
        } else {
                $('.add-tag').addClass("disabled");
                $('.remove-tag').addClass("disabled");
                console.log('got unchecked');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: You're issue is that you are deciding to remove the class based only on the change of the single checkbox, instead of checking if any of them remain checked.

Comment: Also side note; `$(this).is(":checked")` should be avoided as `this.checked` is directly accessable

Answer (score 0):

`if($(this).is(":checked")) {`

This line is checking if the checkbox that just changed, is checked or not.  When really you need to check if *any* of them are checked.

`if ($('#product_table input:checkbox:checked').length)`

Checking to see if there exists any that are checked would result in the class only being added if none of them are checked.

Answer (score 0):

First problem is using `input` as a decedent of `table` tag. For some reason jQuery does not read them. Then in your event you are checking if the input is being toggled not if at lease on input is checked.

See this code:

```js
$(document).on('change', '#product_table input:checkbox', function() {
  // Check how many input checked
  const checked = $("#product_table input:checkbox:checked").length;

  if (checked > 0) {
    $('.add-tag').removeClass("disabled");
    $('.remove-tag').removeClass("disabled");
    console.log('got checked');
  } else {
    $('.add-tag').addClass("disabled");
    $('.remove-tag').addClass("disabled");
    console.log('got unchecked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add-tag disabled">Add Tag</button>
<button class="remove-tag disabled">Remove Tag</button>

<div id="product_table">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

Comment: Good catch.  It most likely doesn't read them because `input` are not valid children of `table` tags, so the markup is invalid.  The browser most likely sticks them in the DOM before or after the table in that case, not inside, in an attempt to "fix" it.